# ||error: unrecognized command line option '-std=gnu++20'; did you mean '-std=gnu++2a'?| error in Codeblocks 20.03 for windows

Tags: codeblocks

After installing codeblocks c files running  but c++ files not running and showing this:
error: unrecognized command line option '-std=gnu++20'; did you mean '-std=gnu++2a'?

Comment: What compiler did you install with Code::Blocks?  You can always edit %AppData%\Roaming\CodeBlocks\share\codeblocks\compilers\options_gcc.xml and change it to be -std=gnu++2a or you could upgrade the compiler to something current so that -std=gnu++20 is recognized.

Answer (score 2):

Under Settings->Compiler select "Other Compiler Option" tab and change "-std=gnu++20" to -"std=gnu++2a".

That solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's a compiler error.  Click on Compiler settings and under Compiler Flags make sure that General has nothing selected.